# Spring AOP Pointcut expression for annotated field

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Is it possible to capture any field with a specific annotation?  My end goal is to inject a value into that field, but currently my pointcut is wrong (not sure of the correct syntax).

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)")
private void annotatedField(){}

@Around("annotatedField()")
public Object injectValue(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {}
```

I believe the pointcut is stating any Method with the annotation.  and I want to change that to say any Field.

Comment: What do you mean by _capture any field_? Spring (proxy based) AOP works with intercepting method invocations only.

Comment: excellent point.  So, perhaps my methodology should be to have the pointcut on the setter method of that field?

Comment: You mentioned _inject_. Why don't you use the built in autowiring mechanisms?

Comment: I can.  I am simply attempting to sugarcoat the injection of specific fields with a more specific and custom annotation.

Comment: Consider using a `BeanPostProcessor` instead.

Comment: related to this:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140938/117089

Answer (score 4):

I think you should follow the advice of *Sotirios Delimanolis* and get as far as possible with Spring on-board means. If then you still think they are inadequate and absolutely want to use aspects to implement your idea, you can use [AspectJ within Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring AOP and utilise the full power of pointcuts like `get()` and `set()` in order to intercept read/write operations on class members (both static and non-static). For example:

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

**Driver application:**

The application reads (`toString()`) and writes (constructor, main method) all fields, among them the annotated `status` field.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @MyAnnotation private String status;

    public Application(int id, String name, String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Application [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application(11, "AspectJ demo", "starting");
        System.out.println(application);
        application.id = 22;
        application.name = "AspectJ field access demo";
        application.status = "running";
        System.out.println(application);
        application.status = "shutting down";
        System.out.println(application);
        application.status = "stopped";
        System.out.println(application);
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class AnnotatedFieldAspect {
    @Before("get(* *) && @annotation(de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation)")
    public void interceptRead(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }

    @Before("set(* *) && @annotation(de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation) && args(newValue)")
    public void interceptWrite(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Object newValue) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + newValue);
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status) -> starting
get(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status)
Application [id=11, name=AspectJ demo, status=starting]
set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status) -> running
get(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status)
Application [id=22, name=AspectJ field access demo, status=running]
set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status) -> shutting down
get(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status)
Application [id=22, name=AspectJ field access demo, status=shutting down]
set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status) -> stopped
get(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.status)
Application [id=22, name=AspectJ field access demo, status=stopped]
```