# Pointcut on fields using annotation and lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, lombok

Introduction: I'm using Java with Spring boot 2.2.2 and Lombok

I got this example class:

```
package com.example.demo.classz;


import com.example.demo.pack.MyAnnotation;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooClass {

    @NonNull
    @MyAnnotation
    private String str;

    private String uninterceptedString;

}
```

I would like to intercept all call to "get"/"set" methods that are annotated with @MyAnnotation. To manage this i created this interface:

```
package com.example.demo.pack;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

And this class to do some operations.

```
package com.example.demo.pack;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class AnnotatedFieldAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.classz.*.get*(..)) && @annotation(com.example.demo.pack.MyAnnotation)")
    public void interceptRead(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        log.info(thisJoinPoint.toString());
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.classz.*.set*(..)) && @annotation(com.example.demo.pack.MyAnnotation) && args(newValue)")
    public void interceptWrite(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Object newValue) {
        log.info(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + newValue);
    }
}
```

Finally to test all, i made a simple controller

```
package com.example.demo;


import com.example.demo.classz.FooClass;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test() {
        FooClass fooClass = new FooClass("Foo");

        fooClass.setStr("Foo2");
        fooClass.getStr();

        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

I can't manage to activate those pointcut and I can't understand why. Could you help me?

I already saw some similar question on StackOverflow like this:
- [Spring AOP Pointcut expression for annotated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493383/spring-aop-pointcut-expression-for-annotated-field)
- [@AspectJ pointcut for all methods of a class with specific annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation)

And some other, but even with their solution i did not succeed.

Some config stuff:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And dependecies section from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
//  compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.5'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `FooClass` must be a Spring component in order to be intercepted by Spring AOP. Is it? I see no `@Component` annotation there.

Comment: No, there isn't and I can't insert it because my FooClass has a constructor. I was reading about AspectJ that should fix this problem, but I don't know yet which changes should I do.

Comment: maybe a small but relevant detail: you set your annotation on field level, but try to intercept (get/set)"methods"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kriegaex mentioned, the FooClass is not a bean managed by Spring Container. You can only intercept a spring bean.

Following changes to the code changes will make the setter methods to be intercepted provided the pointcut expressions are valid.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

    @Data
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Component
    @Scope(scopeName="prototype")
    public class FooClass {

        @NonNull
        @MyAnnotation
        private String str;

        private String uninterceptedString;

    }
```

and obtain the FooClass bean from the application context.

```
FooClass fooClass = ctx.getBean(FooClass.class,"Foo");
fooClass.setStr("Foo2");
fooClass.getStr();
```

Read more on @Component and @Scope to understand the changes done.

[@Component](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)
[@Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html)

Note that only method invocations can be intercepted with Spring AOP. 
Read docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html)

> **== Spring AOP Capabilities and Goals**
>
> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans). Field
>   interception is not implemented, although support for field
>   interception could be added without breaking the core Spring AOP APIs.
>   If you need to advise field access and update join points, consider a
>   language such as AspectJ.

For the same reason the following Spring AOP Pointcut expression would be valid in your case

```
@Before("execution(* com.example.demo.classz.*.get*(..))")
    public void interceptRead(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        log.info(thisJoinPoint.toString());
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.classz.*.set*(..)) && args(newValue)")
    public void interceptWrite(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Object newValue) {
        log.info(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + newValue);
    }
```